# AJAX function returns status 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "check-email",
   data: {email: "name@example.com"},
   success: function(data)
   {
    // success part here        
   },
   error: function(xhr)
   {
    alert(xhr.status);
   }
});
```

This will call another PHP file. But the sad thing is the `error` part is executed always with `xhr.status` printing as 0. What would be the problem?

**Note:**
1. This works perfectly in the local.
2. Both the script, check-email page is located in the same server.
3. The server is secured with https and it is in WWW version.

**Update:**

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
  alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

This prints simply as "**error**".

Comment: Same server, but is it same protocol, port, sub domain, and domain?

Comment: @KevinB: Ya the format looks likethis, `https://www.example.com/script.js` and `https://www.example.com/somefolder/check-email.php`

Comment: Next step is to look at your console and inspect the response headers. Also, add two more arguments to that error handler and inspect them.

Comment: In `error` there are 2 more parameters. Did you check them?

Comment: @u_mulder: What are those parameters?

Comment: the second is text status (which is xhr.status) and the third is the error message generated by jQuery - this is what we're interested in.

Comment: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}`

Is this correct @KevinB?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I tried that long back, in the Firebug console tab I saw similar to this "error (an empty string)". And in chrome I saw "error" simply.

Comment: @nathanhayfield: I changed the POST method to GET and passed the value as `https://www.example.com/somefolder/check-email.php?email=name@example.com` and it produced the desired output.

Comment: @nathanhayfield: I tried that too, but no use. Still I get "error" as error message.

Comment: Ya, I use URL rewrite in both the local and in the server. Opening in the browser as `https://www.example.com/somefolder/check-email/name@example.com` (URL Rewrite format) too produces the desired output.

Comment: If your routing is correct, then I would put a forward slash in front of check-email like so: /check-email

Comment: Also what happens if you use the FQDN?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I tried using the forward slash and at the end too. Didn't worked.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I tried using the direct URL too, and that too didn't worked.

Comment: @SuryaS both in same domain or ajax call to different domain?

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha: Same Domain only. I just used this for validation.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done this as a comment but the code would be a nightmare.

In your PHP page write this somewhere:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_GET, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Now:

1. Open up your Developer tools (Chrome) or Firebug (FireFox) and visit the Network tab.
2. Refresh your page that makes the AJAX call
3. Find the AJAX call to "check-email" in the Network tab and click it
4. What do you see?
5. Also there is a sub-tab called "Headers" in the developer tools, take a look at it

Comment: Method -> OPTIONS; Status -> Load Cancelled; Type -> Pending.